# How to "search" a HashMap then loop the result?

Tags: java, hashmap

So, Im coding some java. And want to search a HashMap then loop the result, this is my hashmap:

```
public HashMap<String, String> messages;
```

BUT! I don't want to loop alle keys, just some. Like searching a MySQL database.

Sorry my english, im Norwegian.

Comment: What do you mean by "loop the result"? What does a `Block` consist of, and how does it define equality and its hash code? What information do you have when looking for one?

Comment: @Jon, first hi. Then, A block in "bukkit" (that is the API) is infomation about x, y and z (location), material and mutch more. What I need is just clean java code. So, just ignore the Block. But, when searching the HashMap I use a parameter called "b" that is the Block.

Comment: @Edvin It sounds like you want to find the associated `Block` given the `BCBlockLog`. Is this correct?

Comment: Forget that, typed new question. :)

Comment: The question is still unclear. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and clarify your question. In particular, if you already know about `get`, what else are you looking for?

Comment: @Edvin what do you mean "both"? It sounds almost like you want to iterate over `messages.keySet` and do `messages.get` per key. I advise you to *not* do this, since you can just do `messages.entrySet`.

Comment: How to messages.get() and then in "Iterator" loop the result.

Comment: @Edvin `messages.get` returns a `String` here, not an `Iterator`.

Comment: What are you trying to loop over?  There's at most one value associated with any given key, and `messages.get(key)` returns that value.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you want to search? What kind of search? A search over the keys? Over the values? What can be used to differentiate between the results and non-results?

Comment: I want like in MySQL with the "LIKE %...%" then loop the result...

Comment: You can't use a `Map` to search for keys "like" another string, or matching a pattern.  You can _only_ search for the single entry that _exactly_ matches the specified key.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you want to iterate through the keys of a HashMap. To do this, you need to use [Map.keySet()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29) method. This will return a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) which contains all the keys for your map. Alternatively, you can iterate through the [entrySet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29) or the [values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values%28%29). (Please look at all the links provided for more details.)

Also, I strongly suggest that you check out [the Tutorial trail on Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html). You should also familiarize yourself with the [Java API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/). In particular, you need to look at the docs for [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) and [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Comment: My +1 was mostly because the links are to the Java 7 API :) , not a super old version.

Comment: @SoboLAN I don't think they changed much since 1.5. Probably 1.4 but that specification is missing Generics.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `equals` `hashcode` properly in your `Block` class and call `get(Object key)` method on `Hashmap` and it will do searching.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access all keys and get the values.

```
public HashMap<String, String> messages;
...
for (final String key : messages.keySet()) {
  final String value = messages.get(key);
  // Use the value and do processing
}
```

---

A much better idea is to just use `messages.entrySet`...

```
for (final Map.Entry<String, String> entry : messages.entrySet()) {
  final String key = entry.getKey();
  final String value = entry.getValue();
}
```

Comment: Did you just copy [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021684/how-to-search-a-hashmap-then-loop-the-result#comment16042111_12021684)? PS if you want to access all keys and values, it's a **better** idea to use `messages.entrySet` and then just use `Map.Entry.getKey/Value`

Answer (score 0):

Still very unclear, but you asked how to do both entrySet() and entryKey().  However, entrySet() returns both Key and Value in one data structure:

```
for( Map.Entry<String,String> entry : messages.entrySet() ) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue();
    System.out.printf("%s = %s%n", key, value );
}
```

But typically you don't do this this way, and instead just simply use the Key to get the Value like so yielding a far simpler method for iteration:

```
for( String key : messages.keySet() ) {
    String value = messages.get(key);

    System.out.printf("%s = %s%n", key, value );
}
```

There exist no facility to "query" a map like MySQL using only the tools included in default Java.  Libraries like apache collections provide Predicates and other filters that can give you query support.  Other libraries include guava libraries.  For example using apache commons collection:

```
List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>(messages.keySet());
CollectionUtils.filter( keys, new Predicate<String>() {
    public boolean evaluate( String key ) {
        if( someQueryLogic ) {
           return true;
        } else {
           return false;
        }
    }
} );

// now iterate over the keys you just filtered

for( String key : keys ) {
    String value = message.get(key);
    System.out.printf("%s = %s%n", key, value );
}
```

Comment: `messages.entrySet` is a much better solution, given how `HashMap` works.

Comment: Define "much better".  It's certainly more code and quite obtuse looking code to look at.  From visual inspection that's not better.

Comment: `HashMap.keySet` iterates over the entries and returns their keys (choosing to ignore the value). You are doing an unnecessary look-up (in the hash table) each iteration for the value your iteration just  ignored when you could just use `entrySet` and avoid it.

Comment: You'd have to prove that's any less efficient by measuring it for me to buy your argument.  I'm willing to say that for all but gigantic maps the difference is imperceptible.  And truly your recommendation has much more of a fell of pre-optimization in the face of no real identifiable problem.

Comment: On the contrary, I'd argue your method is nonsensical. You want every key-value entry in the `Map`. It is very clear you want `entrySet`.